# How to properly export a mongoDB instance between various files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6

I'm tryin to connect to mongoDB database and then export the database connection variable so that I can use it across various files, but when I import that variable in another files, it gives an error.

`server.js`

```
const express = require('express'),
      cors = require('cors'),
      MongoCLient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
      expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql'),
      schema = require('./graphql/schema');

const app = express();

const mongoURL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
    dbName = 'graphql-starter',
    client = new MongoCLient(mongoURL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });

let db;

client.connect(async err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(
            'There was an error while connecting to database. Error: ',
            err
        );
    } else {
        db = client.db(dbName);
        console.log(`Successfully connected to ${dbName} database. ENJOY..!!`);
    }
});

app.use(
    '/graphql',
    expressGraphQL({
        schema,
        graphiql: true
    })
);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    cors();
    next();
});

app.listen(3002, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port 3002.');
});

module.exports = {
    db
};
```

`anotherFile.js`

```
const { db } = require('./server');

db.collection('collectionName').find({}).toArray();
```

In this file, I get an error saying cannot read property collection of undefined? Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.